# Delete all divs that has part of a string - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Heey all,

I want to delete all divs that contains a part of a string.

How can i achieve this?

My old HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="article-options_4"></div>
```

My new HTML looks like this, where 4 is the main article id and 2 is the option id of the article:

```
<div class="article-options_4_2"></div>
```

Here is my current jQuery which checked if the clicked article is false:

```
       if(this.checked == false) {
            $('.article-options' + '_' + $(this).val()).remove();
        }
```

The problem is that when adding new article options with ajax i need to add an extra id to delete every article item when the main article is unchecked. Atleast i think thats the right way...

The problem i faced with this piece of code is that its only deleted one item and not all with the main article ID thats why i added the id of the article options see the html above.

Im curious how i could solve this!

Comment: In the class "article-options_4_2", I understand that 4 is the main article ID and 2 the sub article, am I right?

Comment: You want to delete all div with `article-options_4` class like `article-options_4_1` ||  `article-options_4_3`

Comment: @Salketer and Satpal your both right, that what i want to achieve!

Comment: It would be better to use the data attribute. `<div class="article" data-option1="4" data-option2="2"></div>` then you can just traverse all your div.article and delete the ones that match certain `data('option1')` and/or `data('option2')` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute selector, with a `^` to grab everything that starts with the class name. Do not forget the last `_` or else selecting `article-options_4` will also pick `article-options_40` and `article-options_400` and so on.

```
if(this.checked == false) {
    $('[class^=article-options' + '_' + $(this).val() + '_').remove();
}
```

Comment: This did it!! Im so happy right now!! You made my day :D I will accept the answer! and really nice solution there _ O _

Answer (score -1):

You may use `starting with` [jQuery Attribute Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```
$("div[class|='.article-options_'" + MAIN_ARTICLE_ID + "']").remove()
```

> The [attribute|=value] selector is used to select elements with the specified attribute starting with the specified value.

Comment: From W3C documentation: **The value has to be a whole word, either alone, like class="top", or followed by a hyphen( - ), like class="top-text"!**